# canvas.restore_region() not working

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to follow the instructions on:
http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Animations

Why is the code below not showing the expected behaviour? (see comments in code on what is expected vs. what is observed)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import rand

f, ax = plt.subplots()

# Generate dummy plot
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([0, 10])
ax.imshow(rand(10,10),  interpolation='nearest')
# Until here it works
# If i would add a 
#     f.show() 
# i would see the image

# Save figure
canvas = ax.figure.canvas
background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)  

# Clear Axes
ax.cla()

# try to restore figure
canvas.restore_region(background)
f.show()

# Unfortunatly I only see an empty figure now, Why??
```

Follow-up question:

- I intent to generate a semi transparent copy of `background` on an modified Position in the same axes. (How) Is this possible?

Comment: You need to make sure draw is called at least once before you copy the canvas region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @tcaswell said, you need to force a `draw()` call begore `background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)`. Try

```
...
canvas = ax.figure.canvas
canvas.draw()
background = canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)  
...
```